# Why I cannot modify system-auth-rc

Tags: linux, rhel

I am using REHL 6.4, and login as root by SSH.

I am trying to modify `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`, but meet:

> w:10 Warning: Changing a readonly file

I have bellowing right for accessing this file.

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Also checked `lsattr`, no 'i' attribute on it.

Does any experts know how to deal with this issue?

Comment: Is /etc on a read-only mounted partition?

Comment: No, I can write /etc/passwd file.

Comment: Maybe caused by pam.d folder, other other software lock this file?

Comment: SELinux maybe (not familiar with it though).

Comment: I have disabled SELinux, unfortunately, still cannot write /system-auth-ac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found the root cause is one private security software which was developed by our grovement dev teams. 
The software have one control panel allow us to switch off the security control of /etc/passwd file, then I can edit it then.